# Button with icon and text

Tags: android, button, layout

I would like to make a `Button` like that in Android :

[image: Connexion button]

But I don't know how to do that.
Do I have to use a `RelativeLayout` with some elements (`ImageView`, `TextView`, separator,...) ?

I really don't know the best practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You can use `Button` with Property `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_done"`.

**Refer this.**

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button111111"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_done"
        android:text="Facebook" />
```

**EDIT 1:**

> If you want to do it without using `Button` with Property `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_done"` Then.

**Refer this.**

Create `XML` file named it `Shape.xml` inside `res -> drawable` folder.

If you don't see drawable folder in res directory then create folder named drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="3dip"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dip"
        android:left="10dip"
        android:right="10dip"
        android:top="10dip" />
</shape>
```

**Then refer this Layout.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Submit" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is screen.**

[image]

**Note :** Change your `Drawable` and `Color` as of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

I did for you. Save the image and set as background for the button

[image: i]

Comment: Thanks but I need to translate the text. It's not the good solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

With text and an icon, using the Button class with the **android:drawableLeft** attribute:

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Text Here"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_image"
 />
```

Comment: Thanks ! I have now the drawable in the left. But how can I get the vertical separator ?

Comment: @Jewom Have you checked my answer ?

Comment: @Jewom Check my updated `EDIT 1` part below. It will give you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `<Button>` and set icon you want using i.e. `android:drawableLeft` attribute.

See docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Answer (score 0):

Edit the image to remove the extra area around border and set the image as background